# How to get both Currency code and localized display name in iOS?

Tags: iphone, localization, ios

I want to show both currency codes and its display name in a table view in order to let users select, e.g.

CHF-Swiss Franc

EUR-Euro

RUB-Russion Rubble

I know I can use [NSLocale ISOCurrencyCodes] to get all currency codes, but how can I get the currency display name (Swiss Franc, Euro, etc...) of the currency code? and I hope the dispaly name support localization. Thanks.

Comment: i am facing the same problem now can i get a detailed answer please

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use NSLocale's `-(NSString *)displayNameForKey:(id)key value:(id)value`

Pass in `NSLocaleCurrencyCode` in `key` and your currency code in `value`

Answer (score 5):

```
// Get currency code of Canada
var countryCodeCA = "ca"
let localeIdCA = NSLocale.localeIdentifierFromComponents([NSLocaleCountryCode:countryCodeCA])
let localeCA = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: localeIdCA)
let currencySymbolCA = localeCA.objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencySymbol)
let currencyCodeCA = localeCA.objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencyCode)

// Display it in Chinese
let localeIdCN = NSLocale.localeIdentifierFromComponents([NSLocaleLanguageCode:"zh_cn"])
let localeCN = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: localeIdCN)
localeCN.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleCurrencyCode, value: currencyCodeCA!)

// Display it in the system language
let localeCurr = NSLocale.systemLocale()
localeCurr.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleCurrencyCode, value: currencyCodeCA!)
```

[image]